# Blender not responding when I play animation

Tags: animation, performance

This is my animation, just about 285 frames, 78 keyframes

[image]

When I play animation, Blender is not responding

And here is Blender status in Task Manager. I think it isn't so strong

[image]

What's the problem? What should I do?

Please answer soon. I need to finish it as soon as possible

Comment: What is there on the other layers? If you can share the .blend file it will be easier to answer, as I believe there isn't enought information

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1etiB5FTsu7ET2I7BkwiHbt8AQH2iQ0gC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the .blend file. other layers are my cloth that was hidden. it in 19 layers, i don't know why